# Is it possible to get Authy Code via API?

Tags: twilio, authy

not sure if this is possible - but I would like to get a passcode from the Authy app via API ( so I can log in programmatically ).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is not an API for this. Adding 2FA to an account is intended to stop automatic logins and require a user to produce a code from something they have (in this case, their phone number and authorised device), so side-stepping this is not supported or recommended.

Comment: Albeit in the use case of automating logins on the very trusted device itself, it's more of a convenience than a security risk by itself (e.g. you have Authy on your trusted device, and you need to copy the token to login to another app on the device). The caveat here, though, is that exposing the tokens programmatically could lead to leakage to unwanted 3rd party apps.